# How do I eliminate duplicates when using TEXTJOIN in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am currently using *TEXTJOIN* get all interview dates for a matching name. This is working fine except there are duplicates.

This is typical output for a name with a lot of interview dates:

```
03/06/19, 03/06/19, 03/06/19, 03/06/19, 03/06/19, 03/06/19, 04/06/19, 04/06/19, 
04/06/19, 04/06/19, 04/06/19, 04/06/19, 04/06/19, 04/06/19, 05/06/19, 05/06/19, 
05/06/19, 05/06/19, 05/06/19, 05/06/19, 06/06/19, 06/06/19, 06/06/19, 06/06/19, 
06/06/19, 06/06/19, 06/06/19, 07/06/19, 07/06/19, 07/06/19, 07/06/19, 07/06/19, 
07/06/19, 14/06/19, 16/06/19, 20/06/19
```

I need to remove the duplicates and only show unique values. I prefer to not remove them from the source data but instead modify the *TEXTJOIN* formula.

`C22` contains the name and `TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview]` contains all interview dates.
I am currently using this:

> {=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableOfInterviewDates[Name]=C22,TEXT(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview], "DD/MM/YY"),""))}

I have googled this problem and tried to modify the following TEXTJOIN with duplicate removal:

> {=TEXTJOIN(" & ",TRUE,IF(MATCH(A1:A6,A1:A6,0)=ROW(A1:A6)-ROW(A1)+1,A1:A6,""))}

and have ended up with this:

> {=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableOfInterviewDates[Name]=C22,TEXT(IF(MATCH(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],0)=(ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview])-ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[[#Headers],[DateOfInterview]])),TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview]),"DD/MM/YY"),""),"")}

Getting quite confused now and getting strange output compared to the above output with simple *TEXTJOIN*:

```
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, 16/06/19, FALSE
```

Currently using this but have duplicates:

> {=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableOfInterviewDates[Name]=C2,TEXT(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview], "DD/MM/YY"),""))}

This seems to be the way forward but I am not doing something right:

> {=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableOfInterviewDates[Name]=C22,TEXT(IF(MATCH(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],0)=(ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview])-ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[[#Headers],[DateOfInterview]])),TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview]),"DD/MM/YY"),""),"")}

Comment: Move the `TEXT...` to after the second `IF`

Comment: Hi AAA, I have tried this: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableOfInterviewDates[Name]=C2,IF(TEXT(MATCH(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],0)=(ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview])-ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[[#Headers],[DateOfInterview]])),TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview]),"DD/MM/YY"),""),"") however the output ends up like this: FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DD/MM/YY, FALSE

Answer (score 2):

Try amending your formula as follows...

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TableOfInterviewDates[Name]=C22,IF(MATCH(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],0)=(ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview])-MIN(ROW(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview]))+1),TEXT(TableOfInterviewDates[DateOfInterview],"DD/MM/YY"),""),""))
```

...confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.